# Apache wont start but shows no errors

Tags: apache2, apache

I rebooted a CentOS 6.2 VM (running Virtualmin) and it hung on startup when it was "starting httpd". Booted from a live CD, removed the script that started apache from rc3.d. Server started, now I can SSH into it. Kept trying to troubleshoot:

```
> httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   May 16 2012 22:32:26
```

but I cant start it. it hangs on "starting httpd", as it did during boot up.

```
> service httpd status
httpd is stopped
```

I cant even test the config, "apachectl configtest" just stays there until I hit CTRL-C. I also tried to start apache with all LoadModule directives commented out. The only compiled in modules are:

```
> apachectl -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

I tried to reload all apache config (via webmin backup restore) and still no go.

I read in a couple places that when this happens it can have something to do with SSL certs. I tried to run it with SSLEngine off in ssl.conf. I tried "yum reinstall httpd".

Here are the directives for the default server

```
ServerTokens Min                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (44)
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (57)
TimeOut 60                                                 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (69)
KeepAlive on                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (75)
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (82)
KeepAliveTimeout 5                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (88)
<IfModule prefork>                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (101)
StartServers 2                                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (102)
MinSpareServers 2                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (103)
MaxSpareServers 5                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (104)
ServerLimit 64                                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (105)
MaxClients 64                                             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (106)
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (107)
</IfModule>                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (108)
Listen *:80                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (135)
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (149)
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (150)
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (151)
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (152)
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (153)
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (154)
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_def ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (155)
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (156)
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (157)
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (158)
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_g ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (159)
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (160)
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_def ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (161)
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (164)
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (165)
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (167)
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (168)
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (169)
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (170)
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (171)
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (172)
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (174)
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (175)
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (178)
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (181)
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (182)
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (183)
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (184)
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (185)
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (187)
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (188)
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (189)
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (196)
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (197)
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.s ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (198)
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (199)
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (200)
Include conf.d/*.conf                                     /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (220)
User apache                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (241)
Group apache                                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (242)
ServerAdmin root@localhost                                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (261)
UseCanonicalName Off                                      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (284)
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (291)
<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (302)
 AllowOverride None                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (303)
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (330)
 AllowOverride None                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (337)
 Order allow,deny                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (342)
 Allow from all                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (343)
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (400)
AccessFileName .htaccess                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (407)
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
 Order allow,deny                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (414)
 Deny from all                                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (415)
 Satisfy All                                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (416)
</Files>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (423)
DefaultType text/plain                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (434)
<IfModule mod_mime_magic>                                 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (441)
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (443)
</IfModule>                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (444)
HostnameLookups Off                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (454)
ErrorLog logs/error_log                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (482)
LogLevel warn                                             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (489)
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"  ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (495)
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (496)
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer                     /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (497)
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent                          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (498)
CustomLog logs/access_log combined                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (524)
ServerSignature Off                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (534)
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (549)
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
 Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (552)
 AllowOverride None                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (553)
 Order allow,deny                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (554)
 Allow from all                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (555)
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"                 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (574)
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
 AllowOverride None                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (581)
 Options None                                             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (582)
 Order allow,deny                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (583)
 Allow from all                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (584)
</Directory>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HT ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (602)
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compr ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (609)
AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (611)
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (612)
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (613)
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (614)
AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (616)
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (617)
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (618)
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv     /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (619)
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (620)
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (621)
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (622)
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (623)
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (624)
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (625)
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for                                 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (626)
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (627)
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu                          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (628)
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh . ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (629)
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (630)
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core                              /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (631)
AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..                                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (633)
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README                      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (634)
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (635)
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (636)
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (642)
ReadmeName README.html                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (660)
HeaderName HEADER.html                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (661)
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *, ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (667)
AddLanguage ca .ca                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (707)
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (708)
AddLanguage da .dk                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (709)
AddLanguage de .de                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (710)
AddLanguage el .el                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (711)
AddLanguage en .en                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (712)
AddLanguage eo .eo                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (713)
AddLanguage es .es                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (714)
AddLanguage et .et                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (715)
AddLanguage fr .fr                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (716)
AddLanguage he .he                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (717)
AddLanguage hr .hr                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (718)
AddLanguage it .it                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (719)
AddLanguage ja .ja                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (720)
AddLanguage ko .ko                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (721)
AddLanguage ltz .ltz                                      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (722)
AddLanguage nl .nl                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (723)
AddLanguage nn .nn                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (724)
AddLanguage no .no                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (725)
AddLanguage pl .po                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (726)
AddLanguage pt .pt                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (727)
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (728)
AddLanguage ru .ru                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (729)
AddLanguage sv .sv                                        /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (730)
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (731)
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (732)
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr  ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (741)
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback                     /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (748)
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (757)
AddType application/x-compress .Z                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (777)
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (778)
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (783)
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (784)
AddHandler type-map var                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (806)
AddType text/html .shtml                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (814)
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (815)
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (853)
<IfModule mod_negotiation>                                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (855)
<IfModule mod_include>                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (856)
<Directory "/var/www/error">
 AllowOverride None                                       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (858)
 Options IncludesNoExec                                   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (859)
 AddOutputFilter Includes html                            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (860)
 AddHandler type-map var                                  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (861)
 Order allow,deny                                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (862)
 Allow from all                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (863)
 LanguagePriority en es de fr                             /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (864)
 ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (865)
</Directory>
</IfModule>                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (886)
</IfModule>                                               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (887)
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive                      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (893)
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (894)
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (895)
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (896)
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (897)
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishi ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (906)
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully            /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (907)
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully               /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (908)
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully      /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (909)
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (910)
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully                /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (911)
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-care ..  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (912)
SSLProtocol +SSLv3 +TLSv1                                 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (913)
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!SSLv2:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (914)
TraceEnable Off                                           /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (915)
NameVirtualHost 184.95.32.197:80                          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (916)
NameVirtualHost 184.95.32.197:443                         /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (917)
NameVirtualHost 184.95.32.195:80                          /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (918)
PidFile run/httpd.pid                                    /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (1454)
LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so            /etc/httpd/conf.d/000_mod_sed.conf (1)
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_sec ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf (3)
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_uni ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/00_mod_security.conf (4)
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so              /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf (7)
AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl                     /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf (10)
FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid                           /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf (13)
FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm       /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf (14)
ScriptAlias /mailman/ /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/         /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (5)
<Directory /usr/lib/mailman/cgi-bin/>
 AllowOverride None                                     /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (7)
 Options ExecCGI                                        /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (8)
 Order allow,deny                                       /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (9)
 Allow from all                                        /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (10)
</Directory>
Alias /pipermail/ /var/lib/mailman/archives/public ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (14)
<Directory /var/lib/mailman/archives/public>
 Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks             /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (16)
 AllowOverride None                                    /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (17)
 Order allow,deny                                      /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (18)
 Allow from all                                        /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (19)
 AddDefaultCharset Off                                 /etc/httpd/conf.d/mailman.conf (20)
</Directory>
LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_evasive.conf (3)
<IfModule prefork>                                          /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (5)
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so                   /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (6)
</IfModule>                                                 /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (7)
AddHandler php5-script .php                                /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (15)
AddType text/html .php                                     /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (16)
DirectoryIndex index.php                                   /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf (22)
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so                   /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (12)
Listen *:443                                               /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (18)
SSLSessionCache shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000 ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (35)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300                                 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (36)
SSLMutex default                                           /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (41)
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256               /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (53)
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin                              /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (54)
SSLCryptoDevice builtin                                    /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (66)
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!SSLv2:!EXP:+HIGH:+MEDIU ..  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf (222)
Alias /usage /var/www/usage                           /etc/httpd/conf.d/webalizer.conf (6)
<Location /usage>
 Order deny,allow                                     /etc/httpd/conf.d/webalizer.conf (9)
 Deny from all                                       /etc/httpd/conf.d/webalizer.conf (10)
 Allow from 127.0.0.1                                /etc/httpd/conf.d/webalizer.conf (11)
 Allow from ::1                                      /etc/httpd/conf.d/webalizer.conf (12)
</Location>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that booting into a different kernel (default was [Atomic Rocket Turtle ASL](http://www.atomicorp.com/products/asl.html)) allowed httpd to start fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was he had installed a release candidate for modsecurity 2.7, and this was not caused by the kernel.

Comment: It wasnt said that it was caused by the kernel, but it conflicted with the ASL provided kernel. Also, it was personnel at Atomic Support that installed a dev branch of mod_sec, not @Gaia.