# httpd won't start and no error

Tags: linux, apache

httpd won't start when I run:
`service httpd start` or `service httpd restart`

I don't get error apart from `[FAILED]` bit in red.

`/var/log/httpd/error_log` is empty.

`/var/log/message` has line below:

```
Nov 15 13:23:06 localhost kernel: audit(1384521786.787:32): avc:  denied  { name_bind } for  pid=31935 comm="httpd" src=8000 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:soundd_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket
```

Any idea why it won't start or any solution?

Looked at this: [Apache wont start but shows no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238771/apache-wont-start-but-shows-no-errors)

I haven't rebooted the system yet though which is last option.

Thanks

```
[root@localhost ~]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Sep 11 2006 09:43:00

[root@localhost ~]# service httpd status
httpd is stopped
```

Comment: Isn't it message from SELinux? Try to disable it or tune (if it's that).

Comment: Yeah, thats it. SELinux is enabled in Fedora by default. Patrick gave you (if problem lies in SELinux) right answer.

Comment: good to know that SELinux is enabled by default in Fedora, didn't know that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message from `/var/log/message` looks like SELinux is on.

Try: `getenforce`, it reports whether SELinux is enforcing, permissive, or disabled.

If it's on enforcing, `setenforce 0` to see if that's whats causing the problem.

If it realy was SELinux you should set the proper settings and reactivate it ;-)
Also turning SELinux off by using `setenforce 0`, only lasts until the next reboot!
Permanently turning it off by changing `SELINUX=enforcing` to `SELINUX=permissive` in `/etc/selinux/config`.

---

My second guess would be that iptables/firewalld is blocking the port for httpd.

Comment: so? Fedora Linux has SELinux too, even though i think it's initial on permissive, have you tried turning it off?

Comment: OK! I didn't know that, since I'm not familiar with administrator bits at all and have no knowledge. Anyway it solved the problem. Thank you very much. Learned something!

Comment: thank you, this was very useful