# httpd is not starting

Tags: linux, apache

I am root and I can't start httpd.

I executed `/etc/init.d/httpd status` and got:

> httpd is stopped

when I try `/etc/init.d/httpd start`, I get:

> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs
>                                                             [FAILED]

I thought it might be hung so I checked `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80`.

I got nothing.

I checked `/var/log/httpd/error.log` and it has nothing related to that

Just to try, I tried `/etc/init.d/httpd reload`
I got `[FAILED]`.

What do I need to do?

Comment: I think this one may answer your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001423/httpd-wont-start-and-no-error

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643780/apache-error-address-already-in-use-make-sock-could-not-bind-to-address/46693976#46693976


- Files defined inside conf.d would have Listen port as 80 multiple times in multiple files which can cause this issue.
- Seems port 80 is used by some other process, it can be checked by "netstat -anp|grep :80"

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need find out which service occupy the port 80

```
netstat -anp |grep LISTEN |grep ":80"
```

with this cmd you will learn the service and if it's not the service you want stop and it start your httpd (apache) service.

For my server its nginx not apache and the response of the cmd is like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10266/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      10266/nginx: master
```

which means pid : 10266 (nginx) is useing port 80

Answer (score 0):

grep the process and kill them . Then after try to restart the apache. This might solve your problem.

```
ps -ef | grep httpd

kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure about "listen PORT" config in your config file

i mean you can not have two line with

```
Listen 80
```

in your httpd.conf file (OR one Listen 80 in httpd.conf and one in another config file like welcome.conf)