# Apache error: Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

Tags: apache, ssl, https, apache2, httpd.conf

Apache error while starting:

```
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443

*Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/http-apache2 start") ]
(125)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs*

Listen 443 is added in ssl.conf.
Listen 80 is added in httpd.conf.
```

**HTTPD.conf file:**

```
DocumentRoot "/var/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also getting the following error in error_log file:

```
configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!:index.html**
index.html's location : /var/apache2/htdocs
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Files defined inside conf.d would have Listen port as 443 multiple times in multiple files which can cause this issue.
2. Seems port 443 is used by some other process, it can be checked by "netstat -anp|grep :443"

Answer (score 4):

I had to comment out

> Listen 443 https

in /etc/.../conf.d/ssl.conf after an upgrade to httpd version **2.4.6-80**.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line after listening port

```
#You will have 
    Listen 443 https
#add NameVirtualHost entry after that,
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

and restart httpd server, hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks! but again I'm getting the following errors:   (125 )Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down - while restarting, &                                                 
                                                                                                
configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: in error log file

Comment: Are you using Linux system?

Comment: provide your whole config file containing virtual host.

Comment: Im using solaris system

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I had. Not sure why it suddenly reared it's ugly head, but I suspect a newer version of apache(httpd) perhaps? Anyways, I had some backup files for ssl.conf as well as an rpmsave that has the Listen 443 https directive. I made a backup directory and move all other unnecessary files to BACKUP and uncommented directive in ssl.conf. Then I restarted httpd and viola - no more error.
Probably a yum update started the issue out of nowhere - my best guess. I am thinking the IncludeOptional conf.d/conf directive in httpd.conf is what causes this. It's including all conf files under /etc/httpd/conf.d. So if you make copies of ssl.conf that will trigger this issue if saved here. RPMsave also caused this.